# ¿Por qué prevaleció "resolver" en vez de "solver"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, verbos

En español se usa el verbo *[resolver](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WBV06OC)* como "solucionar un problema, una duda, una dificultad o algo que los entraña". Sin embargo, me llama la atención la forma de construir la palabra. Según el DLE, su etimología es:

> ```
> Del lat. resolvĕre, de re- 're-' y solvĕre 'soltar, desatar'.
> ```

Es decir, en latín ya se decía *resolvĕre*, pero también existía un verbo *solvĕre* que llegó hasta el español, dado que aún aparece en el DLE:

> **[solver](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YJmavLR)**
>
> ```
> Del lat. solvĕre.
> ```
>
> 1. tr. desus. Resolver una duda.
> 2. tr. desus. Hallar la solución de un problema.

Es decir, es sinónima de *resolver* y se parece mucho más al *[solve](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/solve)* inglés, que también viene de *solvĕre*. ¿Por qué en español prevaleció la forma *resolver*, más larga? ¿Cuándo quedó *solver* en desuso? ¿Se llegó a usar esta ampliamente en algún momento?

Answer (score 2):

Desafortunadamente, `solver` y `resolver` todavía no tienen entradas en el Nuevo Diccionario Histórico del Español (donde, creo, podrías encontrar una respuesta confiable al por qué quedó en desuso y cómo evolucionó su significado).

En cuanto a tu segunda pregunta (¿cuándo quedó en desuso?):

Sospecho que tiene más de tres siglos. Una búsqueda en el [Nuevo Tesoro Lexicográfico de la Lengua Española](http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/diccionarios-anteriores-1726-1992/nuevo-tesoro-lexicografico) (NTLLE), revela que la entrada más antigua es del Autoridades (1739). Sin embargo, en la entrada se especifica que es una voz en desuso:

> SOLVER. v.a. Desatar, o resolver. Es voz tomada del Latino *Solvere*, que vale lo mismo: pero **ya no tiene uso**.

Una búsqueda en el [Corpus del Diccionario Histórico del Español](http://www.frl.es/Paginas/default.aspx) revela que el último registro (en España) del uso de `solver` es de 1811 —hay un registro boliviano de 1910—.

Curiosamente, en el NTLLE, la entrada más antigua para `resolver` es de 1495.

Lo que me parece aún más interesante es que, según el Diccionario Vox, *solvere* tiene un significado bastante alejado del que le dimos a la palabra `solver` en español (o al menos al que está señalado en el DLE y en el Autoridades de 1739):

> *Solvere*, desatar || levar anclas, zarpar || dejar libre de [...]. || pagar un crédito [...].

Answer (score -3):

No me baso en casi nada, pero creo que 'solver' y 'resolver' son dos palabras diferentes, de las cuales, por su similitud, "solver" quedó eliminado.

Pudo haber sido que 'solver' era para encontrar una solución a una nueva situación.

Me baso en que en latín ***solvere*** no quería decir "solucionar": quería decir "soltar, liberar", probablemente por representar los problemas como un nudo o una cadena.

Sin embargo 'resolver' es cuando algo se vuelve a hacer o restablecer.

Ejemplos:

> Liberar a alguien que ha sido un esclavo toda su vida: solver
>   Liberar a un prisionero: resolver 
>   Solucionar un problema aritmético: solver
>   Reparar un puente: resolver

Ahora encuentro muchos más usos para 'resolver' que para 'solver' y por tradición oral y malas interpretaciones pues 'solver' quedó aislado, únicamente para la creación de "soluciones químicas".

Comment: Mike, creo que necesitas más carriage returns en los ejemplos; encuentro muchos **más** usos etc. quizás.